# 74HC04 Propagation Delay at 3.3 Volts

Tags: logic-gates, delay

I'm looking to delay a clock signal with a pair of inverters (74HC04.) The circuit is 3.3 Volts, and the data sheets for the HC logic group only list 4.5 and 2.0 Volt tpd. Is linear interpolation sufficient to determine the propagation delay? As I recall, the curve is non-linear, so would the delay be more like what's shown for 4.5 or 2.0 Volts?

Comment: If the manufacturer doesn't provide this information then you won't get reliable data from us either. Furthermore, the only values in the datasheet that you can count on are the maximum delays...the actual delay can be much less and can vary from gate to gate on the same chip.

Answer (score 4):

TI [recommends linear interpolation](https://e2e.ti.com/support/logic/f/151/t/793508). Other manufactuers appear to be silent.

But even if you had a device (like the (SN)74AHC04) that specifies values for 3.3 V, the min…max range is so wide that you could not predict the actual propagation delay.

To get an adjustable delay, use something like an R-C circuit in front of a Schmitt-trigger buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Given the 'hockey stick' shape of the curve of typical propagation delay (figures for the NXP part)

```
2 V   25 ns
4.5 V  9 ns
6 V    7 ns
```

guessing at the 'right' interpolation is not appropriate. The curve obviously has a knee somewhere below 4.5 V, and you have no idea where it is from these figures. The best you can do is to treat 25 ns and 9 ns as upper and lower bounds on the likely figure, and measure a part. Measure it at 3 V and 3.6 V as well, just in case the knee is in that range (perhaps that's why they don't give 3.3 V figures?)

However, when you look at the max figures, 85 ns for 2 V, and 14 ns for 6 V, you should see the futility of trying to get any predictable or reproducible delay out of inverter gates like this.

Answer (score 1):

Linear interpolation between 2.0 V and 4.5 V will overestimate the value a lot. In catalogs [over at TI](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/posts/it-s-all-in-the-family-a-brief-guide-to-logic-family-selection) you can find curves like this here:

[image]

It allows you to predict with some margin what you can expect at a specific supply voltage. The 3.3 V value will be *typically* much closer to the 4.5 V value than to the 2.0 V value.

Comment: But make sure to never, ever design a circuit around "typical" values, no matter how they are derived.